# Remove object of array schema if the ID does not exist from another array schema

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I do have 2 different schemas, one for the user and one for the jobs.
Job has something like manage which is an array of objects and there goes the ID of the user that applied for that job and the ID of the job into user which has an array messages.
If I delete that Object of manage from database then when I get the messages of the user I want to check if that my ID it is into manage, if not then $pull/delete the object with the remaining ID.

Below is what I tried

Job Schema.

```
manage_: [{
   _id: false,
   createdAt: Date,
   userId: String,
   contactedID: String,
   listPosition: Number,
   note: String,
}]
```

User Schema.

```
{
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String,
 messages: [{
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   userId: String,
   messageID: String,
   jobId: String,
   timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 },
],
}
```

This is the function of the controller which is getting called from the API.

```
    async userJobMessages(req, res , next) {
                //req.params.id it is always the authenticated ID
        let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        let fromDate = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000);
            user.messages.map(async (t) => {
            let job = await Job.find({ _id: t.jobId });

            console.log(job, "T")
            if (job.length < 1) {
                let test2 = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                    $pull: {
                        messages: {
                            jobId: t.jobId,
                        }
                    }
                }, { new: true });

            }});


        res.status(200).json({
            messages: user.messages,
        });
    },
```

I tried somehow to find if my ID exists into manage if not then delete that jobID from my messages.

Based on what @nimrodserok said this is the following which still not working.
I am getting an error message like this.
****(node:47922) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: let not supported****

```
async userJobMessages(req, res , next) {
        let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        let fromDate = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000);
    
            User.aggregate([
                {$match: {_id: req.params.id}},
                {$lookup: {
                    from: "jobs",
                    let: {jobIds: "$messages.jobId", userId: {$first: "$messages.userId"}},
                    pipeline: [
                      {$match: {$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "$$jobIds"]}}},
                      {$project: {manage_: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$manage_",
                              cond: {$eq: ["$$this.userId", "$$userId"]}
                            }
                      }}},
                      {$match: {"manage_.0": {$exists: true}}},
                      {$project: {_id: {$toString: "$_id"}}}
                    ],
                    as: "jobs"
                }},
                {$set: {
                    messages: {$filter: {
                        input: "$messages",
                        cond: {$in: ["$$this.jobId", "$jobs._id"]}
                    }}
                }},
                {$unset: "jobs"},
                {$merge: {into: "users"}}
              ])

        res.status(200).json({
            messages: user.messages,
        });
    },
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use 2 queries, or 1 with lookup, instead of your current 3 queries. You can start from the `jobs` collection and find all jobs with the `userId`. Then go to `users` collection and pull all jobs that are not in that list

Comment: Currently it is not quite clear what you are looking for. Your question can be better explained with sample data and expected output.

Comment: @nimrodserok yeah something like that

Comment: I think you mean: `async userJobMessages(req, res , next) {
        let user = await User.aggregate(...)
        res.status(200).json({
            messages: user.messages,
        });
    }` Currently your `user` variable is assigned by `findById`, thus it is ignoring the aggregation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do it on a single query with `$lookup`:

1. Fins the relevant `user`
2. Using `$lookup`, find all `jobs` listed on this user, but keep only the `_ids` of `jobs` that the `user` is listed on their `manage_`. Assign them to `jobs` key.
3. Filter the `user` `messages` to keep only jobs with `_ids` from our `jobs` list.
4. `$unset` the `jobs` key
5. `$merge` back into the `users` collection to update the user

```
const user = await User.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: req.params.id}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "jobs",
      let: {jobIds: "$messages.jobId", userId: {$first: "$messages.userId"}},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "$$jobIds"]}}},
        {$project: {manage_: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$manage_",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.userId", "$$userId"]}
              }
        }}},
        {$match: {"manage_.0": {$exists: true}}},
        {$project: {_id: {$toString: "$_id"}}}
      ],
      as: "jobs"
  }},
  {$set: {
      messages: {$filter: {
          input: "$messages",
          cond: {$in: ["$$this.jobId", "$jobs._id"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$unset: "jobs"},
  {$merge: {into: "users"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gMcQd48fTLz)

**EDIT:**

For mongoDB version 4.2 or older you can use [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nNMbecbme3i)

Comment: As what should be db imported ?
because I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: db is not defined

Comment: @nimrokserok It is not deleting.
I can still see the ID of the job into my messages eventhough that Job is deleted from DB.

Comment: @nimrokserok I have added some code tgth with your code

Comment: I updated the call to use `await User.aggregate`. Please use this to fill your `user` variable.

Comment: I have done it but it seems having an issue in mongoose server.
(node:47922) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: let not supported

Comment: What is your mongodb version? Have you try the attached playground?

Comment: @nimrodserom I have done it but it seems it is not working.
 "mongodb": "^2.1.18" I am using and the playground it worked as expected.
But my code is deployed in a cosmosDB on Azure.
Can that be the problem ?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but I think your mongodb version is not "^2.1.18". This may be your mongoose version. I need to know what is your mongoDb version, because if it is under 4.2, this can explain the `let` issue, but this is a really old version...

Comment: In my package json I do have smthg like this.
 `"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.11.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongo-db": "^1.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "pdf-creator-node": "^1.4.1",
    "socket.io": "^3.1.2"
  },`

Comment: This is not defined on your code. It is probably defined on your cosmosDB

Comment: As  `"apiProperties": {"serverVersion": "4.22},` seems this to be on Azure

Comment: mongoDB version 4.2 [supports `let` on `$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). In this case I don't know what the problem is...Did you change the code on your question according to my answer? Because right now the code over there is not correct

Comment: Yeah I have changed it, only here u have done an error.
`{$match: {_id: req.params.id)}}` should be like `{$match: {_id: req.params.id}}` because parentheses should come to the end because u have opened after aggregate
If possible can we use this as chat so we would escape all this comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251691/discussion-between-nimrod-serok-and-thecoderguy).